# Why JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, etc) cannot find module node_modules/standardx/lib/options?

Tags: intellij-idea, standardx

In a mono-repository (Java + Typescript/JavaScript) I tried to configure IntelliJ IDEA <sup>2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-193.5662.53</sup> to use ESLint along with [standardx](https://github.com/standard/standardx) like in the following image:

[image: Configuration image]

As you can see the version of *standardx* is recognized successfully. But, when I open a TypeScript/JavaScript file I get an error from IntelliJ notifying:

```
Initialization error (ESLint). Cannot find module '<project_base_direactory>/node_modules/standardx/lib/options'
```

If I open the `standardx` node module directory, this is the structure:

[image: standardx files structure image]

So,

- Why is IntelliJ trying to find that `lib/options` directory inside *standardx*?
- How can I get rid of this error and get ESLint to work with *standardx*?

Comment: Gosh, what I would give to get an answer to this that actually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**tldr;** `standard` and `standardx` are little more than ESLint Configuration wrappers. JetBrains won't add `standardx` or `semistandard` because they think that reconfiguring ***your*** entire software project to work in ***their*** IDE is the answer to all your teams' problems < /passiveaggressivevoice >.

In the examples ahead, I use Node.JS v14.15.5 and later. I see two options.

**OPTION 1: For new projects, or projects new to `standard` linting**

I have a node.js project that is strictly backend and needs to manage error rules, is all, and I do all my conjuring with JSON.

```
$ cd path/to/project
$ npm i --save-dev eslint
$ npx eslint --init
✔ How would you like to use ESLint? · style
✔ What type of modules does your project use? · esm
✔ Which framework does your project use? · none
✔ Does your project use TypeScript? · No / Yes
✔ Where does your code run? · node
✔ How would you like to define a style for your project? · guide
✔ Which style guide do you want to follow? · standard
✔ What format do you want your config file to be in? · JSON
Checking peerDependencies of eslint-config-standard@latest
The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:

eslint-config-standard@latest eslint@^7.12.1 eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.1 eslint-plugin-node@^11.1.0 eslint-plugin-promise@^4.2.1
✔ Would you like to install them now with npm? · No / Yes
Installing eslint-config-standard@latest, eslint@^7.12.1, eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.1, eslint-plugin-node@^11.1.0, eslint-plugin-promise@^4.2.1

added 68 packages, and audited 350 packages in 3s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Successfully created .eslintrc.json file in /path/to/your/project
```

**BONUS POINTS: Install Snazzy**

```
$ npm i --save-dev snazzy
```

Then de-lint.

```
$ npx eslint . | snazzy
```

...and you are confirmed at the command line, so now configure in your JetBrains IDE (WebStorm, IntelliJ, etc) by pointing the ESLint package to `~/path/to/your/project/node_modules/eslint` and start the party.

**OPTION 2: You head over to JetBrains and point your afterburners at these two tickets.**

1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31624 - `semistandard`
2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29114 - `standardx`

I'll wager that it's much simpler for customers to have an IDE that supports the ***full*** standard{x} suite rather than just ***one*** that was deemed arbitrarily popular enough to integrate as an exception.

- [More on `eslint` config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)
- [More on `eslint-config-standard`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the IDE to format according to standardjs.com's [rules](https://standardjs.com/#standardjs--the-rules) by selecting a predefined code style in *JavaScript Code Style Settings* (Code Style -> Javascript -> Set From -> Predefined Code Style).

If you wish to get hightlighting as provided by eslint-config-standard in addition to eslint plugins, you can **select a path to the ESLint package in the UI** and use a config similar to:

```
{
  "name": "standardx-security-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "~4.18.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "11.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-jsx": "5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "~6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "~3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "~7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "~3.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "standard",
      "standard-jsx"
    ]
  }
}
```

([source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31624#focus=streamItem-27-2753021.0-0))

Comment: Thanks, Oksana. I'll check this ASAP and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, Oksana. This is not really what I need... Actually, I'm trying to run a project which already has configured and working _standardx_ from IntelliJ... so, the issue now is IntelliJ (not being able to integrate with _standardx_, or the other way around)

Comment: Putting a path to standardx package instead of ESLint one isn't a supported configuration.

Comment: That's a pity :( Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Writing that a path to standardx package isn't a supported configuration doesn't cut it on SO. There /must/ be a way.